# Writing a list into the file by using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a list into the file. I used:

```
studentFile = open("students1.txt", "w")
for ele in studentList:
    studentFile.write(str(ele) + "\n")
studentFile.close()
```

As a result, the output was:

```
['11609036', 'MIT', 'NE']

['11611262', 'MIT', 'MD']

['11613498', 'BIS', 'SA']
```

instead of:

```
11609036    MIT    NE

11611262    MIT    MD

11613498    BIS    SA
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.join` to convert each *sublist* into a string:

```
studentFile.write(' '.join(ele) + "\n")
```

You may find the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-343-the-with-statement) statement which creates a *context manager* a more cleaner alternative for opening, writing to, and closing files:

```
with open("students1.txt", "w") as student_file:
   for ele in studentList:
       student_file.write(' '.join(ele) + "\n")
```

The space in between the items can be increased by modifying `' '` or using tab spacing as in `'\t'.join`.

Answer (score 0):

How does your `studentList` list look like? I suspect its a nested list and you need another loop to pick individual elements.

```
studentList = [['11609036', 'MIT', 'NE'],
               ['11611262', 'MIT', 'MD'],
               ['11613498', 'BIS', 'SA']]

studentFile = open("students1.txt", "w")
for student in studentList:
    for ele in student:
        studentFile.write(str(ele) + "\t")
    studentFile.write("\n")
studentFile.close()
```